# how to get fingerprint from a audio file by php?

Tags: php, audio, fingerprint

Im trying to get fingerprint of some audio files (mp3 or wav or ... the format is not important, I can do the convert) by php.
I found something in python and I found something to match them in mysql but I want something to export fingerprint from a audio file and use it in my php project.

any Ideas ?!

tnx

Comment: If it is just a matter of unique identification you can just `md5()` , but if you are looking to a way to make an audio recognition api like shazam, you must know that it is much more complicated than it may looks!

Comment: Im trying the second one :-D I know, but there were some code in python and they work fine, I was wondering that is there anything in php for that or no

Comment: What you can try to do is to call `dejavu` from php with `shell_exec` or system, if you run php under linux. Have a look at this well explained link: http://willdrevo.com/fingerprinting-and-audio-recognition-with-python/

Comment: it sounds promising. Tnx ! ♥